# Get one day old record from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can i get one day old record from database from server . i have use datetime to insert record. below is how record is look like.

```
2013-01-15 23:44:02
```

i have use strtotime('-1 day') but it returns local system time.i want to get one day old record and do some stuff in condition..

Thanx in advance..

Comment: strtotime is the server time from php, you should use the similar date time function in mysql to do the comparison

Answer (score 5):

```
where date(date_column) = DATE_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: there is no `DATE_SUM` function

Answer (score 3):

use `DATE_ADD`

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE DATE(dateCol) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

- [DATE_ADD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM email_record
WHERE DATE(sent_mail) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 DAY) . there is many one day old record but this query give me empty result set.

Comment: what are the records in your table, i have this working demo, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7544/3

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  * from table  WHERE  datefield  < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: you are comparing against a string.

Comment: @JW this query works fine. The date colum is in dateTime format.

Comment: now, but you previous answer won't. you're wapping this `'DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)'`

Answer (score 0):

You will be archiving this with sql query.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE DATE(datefield)=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

`CURDATE()` will return the current `Mysql Server` time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL expr type)

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_sub.asp

Example provided in W3schools

Assume we have the following "Orders" table:

```
Columns: OrderId, ProductName, OrderDate
Values: 1, Jarlsberg Cheese, 2008-11-11 13:23:44.657
```

Now we want to subtract 5 days from the "OrderDate" date.

We use the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT OrderId,DATE_SUB(OrderDate,INTERVAL 5 DAY) AS SubtractDate
FROM Orders
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$yesterday = strtotime('Y-m-d h:i:s','yesterday');
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE datefield = '$yesterday'
```